# How to deal with UV mapping for long sharp faces

Tags: uv, baking

I have few faces in my 3D model that are quite long and have very small angle. These faces, when unwrapped with `smart_project` and projected onto a 1024x1024 image, do not take up even 1px width on the image map, but span almost the entire height - 1024px.

Now this is a problem when baking this image, since the face does not "own" even a single pixel on the image, the `bake_image` operation just treats the "island" as non-existent, but that's not just it, it's baking other island's `bake_margin` on to this 1px row!

I've tried separating such faces into new object and unwrapping them, and it is still the same thing. Also, I can't merge the closest vertices of these faces as that would lead to significant distortion (this is because closest vertices are quite far from each other, given the long height of the face). One other option would be to split the face into smaller faces, hoping smart project would do a better job, but I am skeptical about it.

So, how do I bake images for meshes containing such long, sharp faces?

Comment: Please show your 3D model so that other can help you more easily.

Comment: "...do not take up even 1px width on the image map" Yeah, that's not a good idea to do when UV mapping. Luckily you can have multiple UV maps in Blender, so maybe creating another UV map (and blending it with your existing one) may fix your issue. Or if UV mapping is exceedingly difficult in those regions of your mesh, consider using a procedural texture for just those regions?